# Django populate user model extension / profile model

Tags: django, django-models

So, I created an application and this application needs to save some settings to the user model, [hence I added a model with a OneToOne field / profile model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    play_onload = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I already had some users registered before creating this model and these users need to have entries in the newly created model as well because every user has to have saved settings in the "Manager" application.

My problem is now that, although I ran the migrations and gave the field a default value, the model is empty:

[image: empty model]

This seems logical because Django assumingly only populates the models when a user is created.

But how would one now go about this? Simply patch the database and fill in entries for all already existing users, also altering the user-creation process? Or is there already a simpler and better way to do this?

My manual approach would be simply retrieveing the full list of user ids and creating entries with them, schematically

```
users = User.objects.all()
for user in users:
    Manager(user=user.id)
```

but the problem is that it's manual (and most likely not even 100% correct)

Answer (score 1):

Create a management > commands and run it using manage.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        users = User.objects.all()
        for user in users:
            m, c = Manager.objects.get_or_create(user=user.id)
            m.save()
```